# Jquery smooth scroll animation not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, animated

I'm working on the website:

http://lucasvallim.com/previews/faseambiental/

I used this plugin:

http://cferdinandi.github.io/smooth-scroll/

Please, click on any button on the menu, it won't scroll. Now if you scroll down manualy and click the button, he will animate to the desired section.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like you have fixed it. Was it the duplicate id's or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at your Code and Those Href"" locations in your navigation bar dont appear anywhere else on the page. only #Home is there 2 times.

lets take an example.

```
<a href="#servicos" class="scroll"><li id="menu_text">Serviços</li></a>


<span id="servicos">servicos</span>
```

this should work if you have implanted hte Jquery file correctly

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have multiple tags with same id. For example you have **id="sobre"** at least in two different tags. You should have unique id's, one per tag.

```
<span class="jumptarget" id="sobre" style="background-position-y: 0px;"></span>
<div class="sobre" id="sobre">
```

Perhaps not enough to solve your issue but at least correcting one fault.